# I run a Monero pool and miners aren't receiving payouts! Please help me thank you

Tags: mining-pools, monerod

I run a Monero pool and after finding a block all the XMR was paid to my wallet. Pool miners received 0% of the payout.

Have I set something up improperly? If so how do I fix this issue?

Comment: You have a mining pool? What software are you using? Are you finding blocks? Reward is going to you and not the miners? Let's try and make the question more clear please.

Comment: Yes, I have a pool And found the piece, but pay the full amount to my wallet, purse by miners waiting for payment and the total payment is full of 0

Comment: You should really try and write your question more clearly. It is difficult to understand what your problem is. Some idiots downvoted you because they couldn't understand.

Comment: obviously there's a language barrier here, but if we knew what software he used for the pool, maybe could figure out the question

Comment: Add：My pool will not automatically pay to the miners XMR, a block of the XMR plenary to pay to my wallet, and I am the owner of the pool, my English is poor, I hope you can understand Thank you

Comment: And that's totally not the place for user debugging. Try IRC on Freenode, #monero or #monero-pools.

Comment: Without knowing the software you are using for your pool, this question would be very difficult to answer. As one user mentioned in the comments, I would recommend reaching out to someone on the IRC Freenode channels - #monero and #monero-pools to see if they can help you directly. If you do not have an IRC client, you can use the web client - https://webchat.freenode.net/

Comment: I guess you could send it to them manually.